# Yesod hamlet loop broken down by categories

Tags: haskell, yesod, hamlet

I am trying to loop through a list of products in hamlet each product has a category. I would like to break down the output to group into the categories with a list of products below each category heading. Is there a way to do this in hamlet while looping through my products. What I currently have below is showing the heading for every product. I think I might be going about this all wrong.

```
$if null products
  <p>No products
$else
  <div class="list-group menu">
    $forall product <- products
      <div class="list-group-item">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">#{categoryName $snd product}

      <div class="list-group-item">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>#{productName $fst product} - #{productPrice $fst product}
```

And below is the bit of code thats gets the products from the database of type `[(Product Category)]`

```
products <- runDB $ selectList [ProductName !=. ""] [LimitTo 10] >>= mapM (\qe@(Entity _ q) -> do
    Just category <- get $ productCategory q
    return (q, category))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is to have your yesod controller group the products into categories for you.

For instance, instead of exporting:

```
products :: [Product]
```

export:

```
productGroups :: [ (Category, [Product]) ]
```

and then your template code looks like:

```
$if null productGroups
  <p>No products.
$else
  <div ...>
    $forall (category, products) <- productGroups
      <h4>#{category}</h4>
      $forall product <- products
        <div>...render the product...</div>
```

This way the products appear in groups according to their category.

To create the product groups you can use something like:

```
import GHC.Exts (groupWith)

groupByCategory :: [Product] -> [ (Category, [Product]) ]
groupByCategory ps =  [ (getCategory (head g), g) | g <- groupWith getCategory ]
  where getCategory product = categoryName (snd product)
```

Caveat: This is untested, untried code.

**Update**

In response to your question int the comments, here is a way to group a list of pairs by the second coordinate:

```
import Data.Ord (comparing)
import Data.List (sortBy, groupBy)

groupBySecond :: Ord b => [ (a,b) ] -> [ (b, [a]) ]
groupBySecond pairs =
  let sorted = sortBy (comparing snd) pairs 
      groups = groupBy (\(a1,b1) (a2,b2) -> b1 == b2) sorted 
      result = [ (snd (head g), map fst g) | g <- groups ]
  in result
```

Comment: Hi. My current list of products comes from a database using the code I have added to my question. How do I convert the [(Product, Category)] to [ (Category, [Product]) ]